# How do i convert entries of text file to .csv file using conditions

Tags: python-3.x, csv, text, text-processing

I have .txt file which contain several entries like following

```
.I 3192
.T
The Lincoln Keyboard - a Typewriter Keyboard Designed 
for Computers Input Flexibility
.W
   A new typewriter keyboard, for direct and punched paper tape computer input
will replace the usual commercial keyboard with 88 characters chosen for the 
convenience  of programmers.
.B
CACM July, 1958
.A
Vanderburgh, A.
.N
CA580702 ES March 17, 1982 10:10 AM
.X
1083    5   3192
3192    5   3192
3192    5   3192
```

The file contain multiple entries one after the other. `.I`, `.T`, `.W`, `.B`, `.A`, `.N`, `.X` are all fields in the entry. Every new entry starts with `.I` and continues untill another entry starts. Some entries do not hava one or more field, in other word completely skip one or more field in between.

I am trying to convert the whole text file into csv file in which each row represent one entry in following manner

`content of .I`, `content of .T`, `content of .W`, `content of .B`, `content of .A`, `content of .N`, `content of .X`

If any entry does not have that field, then there should be null value in the csv file at place of that field.

Comment: "I am trying" sounds like you have tried something already. Can you share your approach and highlight what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use appropriate regex and split your text. Possible solution:

```
parts = [match for match in re.split(r'\.[A-Z]\s+', input_text) if len(match) > 0]
```